# Add new column into mysql from another column from select statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `datetime()` column `date_time` in my database.

I need to convert this to `date()` and create a new temporary column `date_field` **till the session ends**.

I've tried this:

```
$query1 = SELECT date_time, date(date_time) as date_field FROM table_name....
```

This works and creates a temp column `date_field` with all the date values for the `date_time`  field

**Problem** : This only works for this query. I also have another query which searches for `date_time` field and thus results into a DB error `Unknown field 'date_field'`.

```
$query2 = SELECT date_field FROM table_name
                                    | This table doesn't have date_field as a column
```

Can this field be created so that I can use this for a time till the session ends ? as we do for temporary tables ?

**Note**: I can't use ALTER to add new column here due to code limitations.

Any ideas ?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us the query that fails

Comment: the second query fails because the table doesn't have `date_field` column as I've created this only in `$query1`. see the edit. I cant do `date(date_time)` again in the second query :(

Comment: can this column be created from query1 itself and remain till I execute query 2 ?

Comment: Since you are using PHP and you require session persistance can't you just store your date in a `$_SESSION` parameter or something? Also, `$query1` isn't creating a temporary column called `date_field`. `date_field` is just an alias applied to the column for the duration of that particular query.

Comment: if both queries uses the same table then you would always use **date(date_time) as date_field** for every query.

Comment: I've edited `$query1`, it do create a new column `date_field` @Drumbeg @Dominick Navarro

Answer (score 1):

In the first query, you dont really create any column, you just return a a column (date_time), run some function on it (date()) and give it an alias name (date_field). This happens only in the result set, and abvioysly cant be used outside of this query.

What you need to do is simply use the same in the second query: instead of `select date field` you need `select date(date_time) as date_field`

Comment: Unless I've gotten it wrong, I think the question is looking for a way to temporarily store the date retrieved from the first query.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but as I said, I can't do this :(. I just want that when I create a column in query1, it should be created till the session ends and can be used in another query

Comment: I dont understand why, but you can create a temp table with this data if you want it. Select does not store the data it returns anywhere. But again- why? You have the data, running the `date` function and giving it a name in non issue

Comment: Yeah, thats a good point. Anyway, I think I need to find an alternate soln to this. Thanks again:)